# $f: G \to C^{×}$ is homomorphism. |G|=n is abelian .prove that $\sum_{g \in G} f(g)$ is 0 or n

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups

> Let $$f: G \to C^{×}$$ is homomorphism, whereas $C^{×}$ is the multiplicative group of non-zero complex numbers, |G|=n and G is abelian.
>
> Prove that
> \begin{align}
> \sum_{g \in G}f(g)&=0,\quad \text{or}\\[1em] \sum_{g \in G}f(g)&=n
> \end{align}

I know how to break abelian group into modulo $n$,
but after that  I could not imagine a homomorphism.

Comment: Where are you stuck/what have you tried/what theorems do you have/etc

Comment: Any thoughts?  Have you looked at some examples?

Comment: i think a particular element of g belongs to G goes to root of unity in C depends on g ' s order

Comment: actually i have problem if G having odd order

Comment: as if n is even the there exist a g such that f(g)= -1 .hence every complex number has addditive inverse in range of f

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Either all elements are sent to $1$ by $f$, or not. If not all elements are sent to $1$, pick an $h\in G$ such that $f(h)\neq 1$. Then compare the two sums
$$
\sum_{g\in G}f(g)\\
\sum_{g\in G}f(gh)
$$

---

The last two lines of the solution:
$$
\sum_{g\in G}f(g) = \sum_{g\in G}f(gh)\\
= \sum_{g\in G}f(g)f(h) = f(h)\left(\sum_{g\in G}f(g)\right)
$$
Look at the first and last term in this chain of equalities, use that $f(h) \neq 1$, and conclude something about $\sum_{g\in G}f(g)$.

Comment: yes the two sums are equal at least i know that

Comment: but what does it conclude about the sum

Comment: @Rajat I added some more reasoning.

Comment: yeah now i get it thanks